# Django unable to hide sensitive variables

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, sentry

I have hooked my app to Sentry, and I'm trying to check if I can prevent sensitive varaiables from being logged.

Here's my code:

```
   @sensitive_variables('user', 'pw', 'cc')
    def get(self, request):
        user = "foobar"
        raise Exception(f"{user}")
```

My expectation was the it would replace the value of `user` with  `stars (**********)`, according to the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/error-reporting/#filtering-sensitive-information

However, the exception printed out its actual value -- and the sentry logs reflected this.

How do i get it to replace the value of sensitive information with stars?

Comment: DEBUG is False ?

Comment: You need to configure this in sentry https://docs.sentry.io/data-management/sensitive-data/

Comment: @SylvianBiehler Debug is set to True

Comment: @Iain ShelvingTon I'm looking to do it programatically since i have many apps on sentry, and I'd rather have the filtering done in code

Answer (score 1):

You can either [configure Sentry](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/python/data-management/sensitive-data/) to hide certain fields/values or you can define a [filter function](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/python/configuration/filtering/)

```
import sentry_sdk

def strip_sensitive_data(event, hint):
    # modify event here
    return event

sentry_sdk.init(
    before_send=strip_sensitive_data
)
```

This will require a little bit of experimentation to get exactly what you want

Comment: is there any i can integrate it with django's @sensitive_variable decorator?

Comment: @nz_21 Feel free to open a feature request for respecting sensitive_variables()! https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-python

Comment: @nz_21 perhaps you'll find https://github.com/untitaker/python-sensitive-variables useful... it's a drop-in replacement for Django's decorator, except that it works for most crash reporting tools.